# karma + mocha + should v7 not working - should is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, should.js, karma-mocha

I am trying to configure karma + mocha + should but I must be missing something since should is undefined in my tests.

According to the [plugin documentation](https://github.com/seegno/karma-should), the only steps to follow are:

> 1.- Add should to frameworks and karma-should to plugins keys in your
>   karma configuration:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'should'],
    plugins: ['karma-should']
  });
};
```

> All should assertions are available in the tests

This is my config:

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "karma": "^0.13.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^0.1.6",
    "karma-mocha": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-requirejs": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-should": "0.0.1",
    "mocha": "^2.2.5",
    "should": "^7.0.2",
  }
```

**karma.conf.js**

```
config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'should'],

    plugins: ['karma-mocha',
              'karma-should',
              'karma-chrome-launcher',
              'karma-firefox-launcher'],
```

**simpleTest.js**

```
describe('theAnswer()', function() {
  it('should be 42', function() {
    theAnswer().should.be.exactly(42);
  });
});


function theAnswer() {
  return 42;
}
```

When I run `karma start` I'm getting:

```
Firefox 39.0.0 (Windows 7 0.0.0) theAnswer() should be 42 FAILED
    theAnswer(...).should is undefined
```

Any idea why??

Comment: It is more easy to include should.js to files section yourself, just add './node_modules/should/should.js' to files before your tests, that is actually what karma-should do for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with the plugin implementation due to a package change in should 7.x.x:

There's an open pull request for this:
https://github.com/seegno/karma-should/pull/1

The current plugin version (0.0.1) works up to should 6.x.x.

**EDIT:** The latest karma-should plugin release (1.0.0) corrects this issue.